# how python display list of all attribute and method using dir(object)?

Tags: python

I was reading python dunder method and came across that the we can have our own definition for built-in method like len(object)
So I created a class otherclass which has definition

```
>>> class otherclass:
        def __len__(self):
            return 0

>>> len(otherclass())
0

>>> dir(otherclass)
['__doc__', '__len__', '__module__']
```

And it does print len of the object and further inspecting I also found **len** dunder method is available in otherclass object using dir

I am wondering how python display the value for dir(object) as there is no **dir** dunder method in the result of dir(otherclass)

Comment: Hint: see what `otherclass.__dict__` prints

Comment: By doing `help(dir)` you might have an idea

Comment: I print these  
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__len__': <function __len__ at 0x0000000003547128>}

Comment: @Vinay what version of python are you using?

Comment: @FHTMitchell From `'__len__': <function __len__ at 0x0000000003547128>` I'd say he's using Python 2.

Comment: Thanks @HigorRossato for response but help(dir) print what is the purpose of dir and I also print help(len) is print their help but len will only work if defined but there is no definition for dir in that otherclass object.  Neither do I inherit object in the class like class otherclass(object)

Comment: Yes @FHTMitchell, how you got this? BTW The full version read like this 2.7.15

Comment: Neither does it define `__str__` or `__repr__`, still those functions work. They just use the default implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean for me (python 3.6) `dir(otherclass)` prints

```
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__']
```

The iteresting one is `__dict__`.

```
otherclass.__dict__ == \
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'otherclass' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__len__': <function __main__.otherclass.__len__>,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'otherclass' objects>})
```

So this holds all the methods/attributes specific to that object. However, where do all the others come from? Well, from the superclass:

`object.__dict__`

```
object.__dict__ == \ 
mappingproxy({'__class__': <attribute '__class__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__delattr__': <slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__dir__': <method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__doc__': 'The most base type',
              '__eq__': <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__format__': <method '__format__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__ge__': <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__gt__': <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__hash__': <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__init__': <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__init_subclass__': <method '__init_subclass__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__le__': <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__lt__': <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__ne__': <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__new__': <function object.__new__>,
              '__reduce__': <method '__reduce__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__reduce_ex__': <method '__reduce_ex__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__setattr__': <slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__sizeof__': <method '__sizeof__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__str__': <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__subclasshook__': <method '__subclasshook__' of 'object' objects>})
```

So `dir` looks for a `__dir__` method, then looks at `__dict__` (or `__slots__`) and then recursively looks up the method resolution order (available as `otherclass.mro()`) at each class in turn.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but I am still not that master in python and didn't understand the much from the code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the Python Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

> If the object does not provide `__dir__()`, the function tries its best to gather information from the object’s `__dict__` attribute, if defined, and from its type object.

Answer (score 0):

`dir` is a built-in function. When it is passed an object it uses the object's `__dict__` (if defined) and its corresponding type object to attempt to display attributes.

Note that built-in `dir` can result in strange outputs if `__getattr__` has been overridden in the object.

Read more:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Addressing comment:
Apologies, I don't have enough reputation to comment.

All objects in Python implicitly have a bunch of special attributes, one of these is the `__dict__` attribute. In Python, classes are objects too. Therefore your `otherclass` class already has a `__dict__`. In your code, try:

```
otherclass.__dict__
```

In the output you'll see some of the output corresponds to the output of the `dir` call.

Edit 2:

Like I said, classes are objects in Python. They implicitly have all of the methods objects have. Try:

```
object.__dict__
```

and you'll find `dir` in there.

Comment: Thanks for response, But even __dict__ is not defined, Clear me if I am wrong based on the code expample shared in my question.

Comment: When I print otherclass.__dict__, I got these output {'module': 'main', 'doc': None, 'len': <function len at 0x0000000003547128>}
There is no dir in the output. FYI, I am using python 2.7.15